# Which Group Policy wins out of two enforced policies with similar settings?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a situation where I need to modify an enforced group policy object, however due to the sensitive nature I must test my results first to one test user.

In order to do this I plan to create new policy object with the same settings, apply the correct modifications there, and then test it only to a particular test user (you get the idea).

Because the main GPO in question is enforced, I have to somehow **make** the test GPO win over the main GPO?

Will the test GPO win over the enforced GPO if I put the test GPO above the main GPO, **enforce it** and with the security filtering apply the test GPO only to the test user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is enforced at the same or higher priority level, yes.  Here is the order of execution.  The setting applied last wins:

Local > Site > Domain > OU > OU Enforced > Site Enforced > Domain Enforced

The winning enforced settings at the same level are determined by precedence order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - if two enforced policies are applied at the same level, the one that is higher in the list will win.

Therefore, if you filter everyone else out of your test policy, this should have the effect that you're looking for.